# Data limit on Zookeeper nodes including parent and child nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper documentation says the maximum allowable size of a data array is 1 MB for a node. Can I store 1MB of data under parent node and 1MB of data in all of its child nodes?

Ex:

```
/parent_node
{
   1MB
}

/parent_node/child_node_1
             {
                1MB
             }

/parent_node/child_node_2
             {
                1MB
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But it is recommended that the actual data size be much less than this limit. Keep in mind that 1MB is combined size of key and value together.

Note that zookeeper is not designed to store large amount of data since its performance seriously degrades under such circumstances.